# Getting type error in open3d Invoked with 100000,0.999

Tags: python, deep-learning, 3d, computer-vision, open3d

TypeError: **init**(): incompatible constructor arguments. The following argument types are supported:
1. open3d.cpu.pybind.pipelines.registration.RANSACConvergenceCriteria(arg0: open3d.cpu.pybind.pipelines.registration.RANSACConvergenceCriteria)
2. open3d.cpu.pybind.pipelines.registration.RANSACConvergenceCriteria(max_iteration: int = 1000, max_validation: int = 1000)

Invoked with: 100000, 0.999

I am getting this error while running the file. I am doing the global registration of open 3d documentation. I am not able to solve this error. I have also updated the version of python and open 3d then also it is not working. can anyone help?

Comment: Hi! Could you please provide the content of file you running as well?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of `open3d`, the type of the second parameter of `open3d.cpu.pybind.pipelines.registration.RANSACConvergenceCriteria` changes:

- Until `open3d` [0.11.1](http://www.open3d.org/docs/0.11.1/python_api/open3d.pipelines.registration.RANSACConvergenceCriteria.html), it expects an int `max_validation`:

```
__init__(self: open3d.cpu.pybind.pipelines.registration.RANSACConvergenceCriteria, max_iteration: int = 1000, max_validation: int = 1000) -> None
```

- From `open3d` [0.12.0](http://www.open3d.org/docs/0.12.0/python_api/open3d.pipelines.registration.RANSACConvergenceCriteria.html), it expects a float `confidence`:

```
__init__(self: open3d.cpu.pybind.pipelines.registration.RANSACConvergenceCriteria, max_iteration: int = 100000, confidence: float = 0.999) -> None
```

Make sure you have indeed updated the version of your `open3d`.